# How does the impl of AsRef<Path> for PathBuf work?

Tags: rust

Here is the implementation that I see in my version of Rust:

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl AsRef<Path> for PathBuf {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &Path {
        self
    }
}
```

It says that the implementation for converting a &PathBuf to a &Path is simply to return self, which implies that &PathBuf is &Path (or that the compiler itself knows that they can be converted automatically)?

These are 2 different structs right? How does the compiler know that this is okay?

Comment: I imagine it is due to the implementation of `Deref` being implicitly called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of type coercion, which you can read about [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html).

First, the `self` in `fn as_ref()` is a valid "coercion site" because it is a function result. The compiler will try to coerce from the type of `self` (`&PathBuf`) to the return type (`&Path`).

Second, type coercion can occur because the case "`&T` to `&U` if `T` implements `Deref<Target = U>`" (see the docs) applies here: [`PathBuf` implements `Deref<Target=Path>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.PathBuf.html#deref-methods).

So what happens is that the compiler implicitly coerces `self` from `&PathBuf` to `&Path` via `Deref`.